# Fewer permission for Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, google-api

In my Chrome extension's manifest.json, I have this entry:

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "someLongIdHere.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
}
```

And I'm using this in background.js

```
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, getToken);
```

Everything is working, but I need to make the extension to ask for fewer permissions. These permissions might scare away potential users:

[image]

In particular, I just want it to ask for these permissions:

- See and edit your spreadsheets
- Create new spreadsheets

My google-fu is failing, can't find how to restrict Google API to fewer permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets) available for the Google sheets api

[image]

If you want to See, edit, create, Sheets then you need either of these

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

your google-fu is not failing you there is just no other option.  Unless you are only after files created by your app in which case you should check the drive.file one.